# set up the captive portal on openwrt

Tags: openwrt, captiveportal

I'm trying to set up the captive portal on openwrt.
I did all the work. And when users connect to the router, they are automatically redirected to the index.html page.
But when the Internet is disconnected, a "internet my not be available" message appears. And Android devices can not detect the captive portal page.

file /etc/config/dhcp

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# cat dhcp

config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded '1'
    option boguspriv '1'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option domain 'lan'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    option logqueries '1'

config dhcp 'lan'
    option interface 'lan'
    option start '100'
    option limit '150'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option dhcpv6 'server'
    option ra 'server'
    option ra_management '1'

config dhcp 'wan'
    option interface 'wan'
    option ignore '1'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
    option maindhcp '0'
    option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
    option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'

config domain
    option name 'connectivitycheck.gstatic.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'apple.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'captive.apple.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'detectportal.firefox.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'gstatic.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'clients3.google.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'connectivitycheck.android.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'msftconnecttest.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'play.googleapis.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'spectrum.s3.amazonaws.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'mtalk.google.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'alt3-mtalk.google.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'alt4-mtalk.google.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'

config domain
    option name 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com'
    option ip '192.168.1.1'
```

I think that android devices send packet ICMP for check internet.
I using iptables drop all ICMP packet. But it did not work again.

Note
This problem occurs only when Android users connect. Ubuntu and Firefox recognize the index page.

Comment: Where is the captive portal page hosted? Also, I do not think you want to set all of these domains to the IP of your router. The purpose of domains like 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com' is for the client's OS to determine if they are behind a captive portal.